# Run an shell script on startup (not login) on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: shell, ubuntu-14.04, startup

I have a build server. I'm using the Azure Build Agent script. It's a shell script that will run continuously while the server is up. Problem is that I cannot seem to get it to run on startup. I've tried `/etc/init.d` and `/etc/rc.local` and the agent is not being run. Nothing concerning the build agent in the boot logs.

For `/etc/init.d` I created the script `agent.sh` which contains:

```
#!/bin/bash

sh ~/agent/run.sh
```

Gave it the proper permissions `chmod 755 agent.sh`and moved it to `/etc/init.d`.

and for `/etc/rc.local`, I just appended the following

```
sh ~/agent/run.sh &
```

before `exit 0`.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: added examples.

EDIT 2: Just noticed that the init.d README says that shell scripts need to start with `#!/bin/sh` and not `#!/bin/bash`. Also used absolute path, but no change.

FINAL EDIT: As @ewrammer suggested, I used cron and it worked. `crontab -e` and then `@reboot /home/user/agent/run.sh`.

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/vsts-fullbuild-ubuntu-vm

Comment: already checked that and could only find startup for Ubuntu 15 or 16, not 14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to see what is wrong if you are not posting what you have done, but why not add it as a cron job with @reboot as pattern? Then cron will run the script every time the computer starts.

Comment: Sorry. Expanded it a bit. I'll try cron job.

Comment: Please use absolute paths without "~". That may help.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, using a supervisor could be a good idea, In Ubuntu 14 you don't have `systemd` but you can choose from others https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_supervision.

If using [immortal](https://immortal.run/post/run.yml/), after installing it,  you just need to create a `run.yml` file in `/etc/immortal` with something like:

```
cmd: /path/to/command
log:
    file: /var/log/command.log
```

This will start your script/command on every start, besides ensuring your script/app is always up and running.